# PyAutoGui cannot paste unicode characters

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want my `pyautogui` to type some Unicode chars(eg:㻵矈궽ꢾ럪በ) and it won't work.
I tried the below:

```
def write(text: str):
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

I also tried this:

```
def write(text: str):
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")
        pyautogui.press("delete")
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
        pyautogui.press("delete")
```

But it still doesn't work. How could I do this?

Comment: might want to take a look at this Github issue: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/186

Comment: also what is your Operating System

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Also, your question title is pretty bad, it should say something about the question. See also [ask].